# Array constant in a formula with non-adjacent cell references

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I need to add an array of non-adjacent cells to my array formula.  I have tried all of the following array constant-like ways and they all give me a "There is a problem with this formula error".

```
'Chart Data'!{A12:A14,D3:D11}
{'Chart Data'!A12:A14,'Chart Data'!D3:D11}
'Chart Data'!{A12,A13,A14,D3:D11}
{'Chart Data'!A12,'Chart Data'!A13,'Chart Data'!A14,'Chart Data'!D3:D11}
'Chart Data'!{A12,A13,A14,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10,D11}
{'Chart Data'!A12,'Chart Data'!A13,'Chart Data'!A14,'Chart Data'!D3,'Chart Data'!D4,'Chart Data'!D5,'Chart Data'!D6,'Chart Data'!D7,'Chart Data'!D8,'Chart Data'!D9,'Chart Data'!D10,'Chart Data'!D11}
```

Entire formula (the array constant goes where the {#####} is):

```
{=SUM(((1-References!M1:M12)*({#####}*(G3:G14+F3:F14-0.11)))+((References!M1:M12)*('Chart Data'!A12:A23*(G3:G14+F3:F14-0.11)))+((H2:H13*X3:X14)+(H3:H14*Y3:Y14)+(I2:I13*(V3:V14-X3:X14))+(I3:I14*(W3:W14-Y3:Y14))))}
```

I am 100% positive that it is this particular array constant that is causing the problem.  I can't move the cells I'm referencing to put them in line.  Is it even possible to reference a non-adjacent range in an array formula? If it's possible, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What formula are you using?  Many will not allow non-consecutive ranges.

Comment: It's just a sum with a lot of other +,-,* inside.

Comment: please add the exact formula to the original post using [edit].

Comment: `sum('Sheet1'!A12:A14,'Sheet1'!D3:D11)`

Comment: so `{#####}` is like `{1, 2, 3, 4}` ?

Comment: yes, but I would like for the {#####} to be {A12:A14,D3:D11}

Comment: Can't be done. There. Problem solved.

Comment: To elaborate on what @Jeeped wrote, an array constant must contain **constants**: strings, numbers, Booleans, errors.  It cannot contain cell references, formulas, and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. The following is very simple and pretty direct so my favorite.

EITHER choose a cell to build your string for your non-contiguous array in OR create a Named Range to do it. I'll show the first as it seems nicest for being able to use the mouse freely, but in both of them you can actually be creative using about how you build the string that will become your array. The main advantage of creating it in a Named Range is no helper cell lying about anywhere.

So, you create that string and then make it an array. Say you have a non-contiguous array needed using cells A12:A14 and C3:C11. You use `joining` and `TEXTJOIN()` like so:

```
="{"&TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,B12:B14,C3:C11)&"}"
```

to create a text string of the values in those cells wrapped with the curly braces ({}) just as if you'd typed it in ("hardcoded it"). It will look like this with the right values in those cells:

```
{1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

but is ain't an array yet.

Now the magic in THIS method. Create a Named Range, perhaps called `String2Array`, and give it a formula of:

```
=EVALUATE(A1)
```

(or whatever cell you used for the above formula creating the text string that you want to be an array). Make the reference absolute. ($A$1... which it will do for you, just don't edit it to be relative. If you use this for similar work, but need it relative, that will work fine, but it just isn't what is needed here.)

Now replace your placeholder in the formula with the Named Range's name (perhaps you DID use `String2Array`). And you're done.

A couple other methods use `INDEX()` or `CHOOSE()` and you can force things to be arrays using the functions `DOLLARDE()` and `IMREAL()` (I found on a helpsite in a 2014 post) and some others do the same kind of thing. In those days, one had to use {CSE} too, but SPILL takes care of that now (with those two weird-seeming friendlies and at least two others). The poster was someone I've seen on this site, `EXCELXOR` was the name for the site, `XOR LX` was the name of the member here though the functions were mentioned in a comment by a Lori. Since he covers, it seems, aspects not usually covered in helpsites, looking up some of his work here, or elsewhere too, might be worthwhile to some folks.

But this method is very direct and therefore easy to maintain. And personally, I love the idea that `EVALUATE()` (must be used IN the Named Range functionality, not cell-side) is the gift that keeps on giving, one wonderfully helpful thing after another.

So many ways. You could even literally build the array in a helper column/row somewhere and reference THAT instead of the non-contiguous addresses. I like the `joining+TEXTJOIN()` approach best because I can use the mouse to easily get all the blocks into the formula since it is a LIVE formula. But you can type out a string fairly easily too and add the {}'s. Or perhaps a user would type a string of addresses and you'd add them like the formula does above. And you can insert actual values (constants) into the string you are building as well if that is appropriate. And you could build it formulaicly... I wouldn't pick that workload first thing off the pile of choices, but if you were going to do it anyway already, then... or if it's a small build.